# PHP get values from text file

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I have a form (author-form.php) that writes names (names and surnames) to a text file. Then another php file (author-list.php) should read and output the names. Names in one "column" and surnames in another "column". This is where I got a problem.

I do understand that it could be done with `strtok` or `explode` but it is not really a good idea because first name can consist of two words. Is there any other approach I could use based on my code?

Form file:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('author-draft.txt', ($firstName = $_POST['firstName'] ?? '') . ' ' . $lastName = $_POST['lastName'] ?? PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents('author.txt', preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', "\r\n", trim(file_get_contents('author-draft.txt'))));

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (strlen($firstName) < 1 or strlen($firstName) > 21) {
        print 'Name should contain 1-21 chars.';
    } elseif (strlen($lastName) < 2 or strlen($lastName) > 22) {
        print 'Surname should contain 2-22 chars.';
    } else {
        header ('Location: author-list.php');
        die;
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Library</title>
</head>
<body id="author-form-page">
<table border="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="33%" align="center">
            <table border="0" width="100%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" width="100%" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href=index.php id="book-list-link">Books</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                    <a href=book-form.php id="book-form-link">Add books</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                    <a href=author-list.php id="author-list-link">Authors</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                    <a href=author-form.php id="author-form-link">Add authors</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <hr>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" width="60%" align="center" id="error-block">
                            <form method="post">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">Name:</td>
                                    <td><input size="40%" type="text" name="firstName" value="<?= $firstName ?>"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">Surname:</td>
                                    <td><input size="40%" type="text" name="lastName" value="<?= $lastName ?>"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">Grade:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="radio" name="grade" value="1" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) and $_POST['grade'] == 1) {echo "checked";} ?>>1
                                        <input type="radio" name="grade" value="2" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) and $_POST['grade'] == 2) {echo "checked";} ?>>2
                                        <input type="radio" name="grade" value="3" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) and $_POST['grade'] == 3) {echo "checked";} ?>>3
                                        <input type="radio" name="grade" value="4" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) and $_POST['grade'] == 4) {echo "checked";} ?>>4
                                        <input type="radio" name="grade" value="5" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) and $_POST['grade'] == 5) {echo "checked";} ?>>5
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td align="right"><button type="submit" name="submitButton">Save</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </form>
                        </table>

...
```

Author list file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Library</title>
</head>
<body id="author-list-page">
<table border="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="33%" align="center">
            <table border="0" width="100%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" width="100%" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href=index.php id="book-list-link">Books</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                    <a href=book-form.php id="book-form-link">Add books</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                    <a href=author-list.php id="author-list-link">Authors</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                    <a href=author-form.php id="author-form-link">Add authors</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <hr>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" width="100%" align="center" id="message-block">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="33%">Name</td><td width="33%">Surname</td><td width="33%">Grade</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td colspan="4"><hr></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9734;&#9734;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
...
```

Comment: How about using CSV format? Or just do the sane thing and use a database

Comment: @ADyson what difference would using csv make?

Comment: Because it would be easier to parse the file and get the right data into each column (although in your current format you could just split each line on the space between the names...until of course you come up against a name like "Jon Arne Riise" or something). I was assuming you were having a problem with reading the data into two columns from the file, is that not the case? Your question was a little bit vague on the subject of exactly where you're stuck at the moment.

Comment: +1 for using a CSV. It’s literally made for what you’re trying to do: store multiple bits of information on a single line. And PHP has built-in functions for parsing CSV files.

Comment: If you just write arbitrary data to a file with no structure how is anyone supposed to know how to read it? Even yourself? CSV is a simple way to structure your data.

Comment: https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-csv/

Comment: thank you, I'll use csv